# Shall we lower case input data for (pre) training a BERT uncased model using huggingface?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

Shall we lower case input data for (pre) training a BERT uncased model using huggingface? I looked into this response from Thomas Wolf (https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/92#issuecomment-444677920) but not entirely sure if he meant that.

What happens if we lowercase the text ?

Comment: the tokenizer should do that for you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tokenizer will take care of that.

A simple example:

```
import torch
from transformers import BertTokenizer
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased', max_length = 10, padding_side = 'right')

input_ids = torch.tensor(tokenizer.encode('this is a cat', add_special_tokens=True, max_length = 10, pad_to_max_length = True)).unsqueeze(0)
print(input_ids)

input_ids = torch.tensor(tokenizer.encode('This is a Cat', add_special_tokens=True, max_length = 10, pad_to_max_length = True)).unsqueeze(0)
print(input_ids)
```

Out:

```
tensor([[ 101, 2023, 2003, 1037, 4937,  102,    0,    0,    0,    0]])
tensor([[ 101, 2023, 2003, 1037, 4937,  102,    0,    0,    0,    0]])
```

But in case of cased,

```
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-cased', max_length = 10, padding_side = 'right')

input_ids = torch.tensor(tokenizer.encode('this is a cat', add_special_tokens=True, max_length = 10, pad_to_max_length = True)).unsqueeze(0)
print(input_ids)

input_ids = torch.tensor(tokenizer.encode('This is a Cat', add_special_tokens=True, max_length = 10, pad_to_max_length = True)).unsqueeze(0)
print(input_ids)
```

```
tensor([[ 101, 1142, 1110,  170, 5855,  102,    0,    0,    0,    0]])

tensor([[ 101, 1188, 1110,  170, 8572,  102,    0,    0,    0,    0]])
```

Comment: Generally speaking, the tokenizer behaviour wrt to case handling is specified in the model's tokenizer_config.json, property do_lower_case.

Answer (score 0):

I think the bert-base-uncased model will lower case the text irrespective of what you pass to the model. You can also try playing with a toy dataset and print the tokens using the BERT tokenizer so as to just confirm.